# How to get the struct file of an open file?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I want to find the path of a file in the kernel module. The only information I have is the file descriptor of the file.

I read some posts and I saw using dentry_path_raw(filp->f_path.dentry,buf,buflen) can get the path, where filp is a pointer of the struct file.

After some searching, I know that "the file structure represents an open file. (It is not specific to device drivers; every open file in the system has an associated struct file in kernel space.) It is created by the kernel on open and is passed to any function that operates on the file".

But how to get this struct file in the first place?

Comment: The struct file exists in kernel space. Find the driver associated with a file, and then you can get the pointer to struct file in the functions operating on the file.

Comment: You can get the `struct file *` from a file descriptor **for the current task context only** with `fget()`. Call `fput()` afterwards.

Comment: @user7176709 Can you elaborate please? Like what is the driver for the file? This is my first time doing something with the kernel module.

Comment: @Ian Abbott: This maybe a silly question, but I did not find a fget() function. Are you referring to fgets()? Is it allowed to use in kernel space? and it does not take file descriptor as one of its arguments.

Comment: I was referring to the kernel function `fget` declared by `#include <linux/file.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

struct `file` is normally passed to the `open` and `release` functions of the kernel module.

In your kernel module, you normally fill a `file_operations` object:

```
static struct file_operations my_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = my_open,
    .release = my_release,
};
```

Then, implement the functions:

```
static int my_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp) {
        // Here you get the `filp`
        return 0;
}
static int my_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp) {
        // Here you get the `filp`
        return 0;
}
```

After installing your module, the system will automatically call `my_open` when an application calls `open()` function for this module, passing `filp` pointer.